# Unspecified errors in searching function

Tags: asp.net, string, list

I have 3 classes: `Item` (`itemId`, `itemName`), `Recipe` (`recipeId`, `recipeName`, `items`), and ItemInRecipe (`itemInRecipeId`, `recipeId`, `itemId`).

My goal is to find recipes that only contain items from a list I choose.

In order to do that, I wrote this function:

```
 public static List<Recipe> SearchingForRecipesByItems(List<string> usersitems) 
        {
            Recipe[] recipesarr = SelectListOfAllRecipes().ToArray();
            List<Recipe> recipes = new List<Recipe>();
            for (int i =0; i<recipesarr.Length; i++)
            {
                recipes.Add(new Recipe
                {
                    RecipeId = recipesarr[i].RecipeId,
                    RecipeName = recipesarr[i].RecipeName,
                    Items = recipesarr[i].Items
                });
            }
            List<Recipe> selected = new List<Recipe>();
            foreach (Recipe r in recipes)
            {
                bool check = true;
                List<string> recipeItems = new List<string>();
                string[] recipeItemarr = SelectListOfItemsInSpecificRecipe(r.RecipeId).ToArray();
                for (int j=0; j<recipeItemarr.Length; j++)
                    recipeItems.Add(recipeItemarr[j]);
                foreach (String item in recipeItems)
                {
                    if (!usersitems.Contains(item))
                        check = false;
                }
                if (check)
                    selected.Add(r);
            }
            return selected;
        }
```

This function uses the following functions:

```
public static DataTable GetInfo_fromTable(string sql) 
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OleDbConnection con = Dbf.GenerateConnection(); //opens the connections with the tables
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
```

```
public static List<Recipe> SelectListOfAllRecipes()
        {
            string sql = string.Format("select * from [Recipe]");
            List<Recipe> list = new List<Recipe>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable(sql);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new Recipe
                {
                    RecipeId = int.Parse(dr["recipeId"].ToString()),
                    RecipeName = dr["recipeName"].ToString(),
                    Items = dr["items"].ToString()
                });
            }
            return list;
        }
```

```
        public static List<string> SelectListOfItemsInSpecificRecipe(int recipeId)
        {
            string sql = string.Format("select [itemId] from [ItemInRecipe] where [recipeId] = {0}", recipeId);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable(sql);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string name = GetItemName(int.Parse(dr["itemId"].ToString())); //gets the item name using its id
                list.Add(name);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

I believed that it would work, since it is a good idea to find the correct recipes, but when trying to send a list of item from an aspx page, it shows so many errors - even in other functions, which I alreadt checked and are working. I tried writing it in different ways, but nothing worked.